# Python Toolbox - Only update parameter when specific parameter changes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, parameters, python-toolbox

I'm creating a Python Toolbox. One input is a workspace and the second is a list of feature classes and tables. The list of feature classes and tables is generated once the workspace is input by the user, using a series of `ListFeatureClasses` and `ListTables`. Annoyingly, once the workspace is input the tool will re-run this code when the user updates ANY of the parameters. This can freeze up ArcGIS for minutes if the workspace contains lots of feature classes/tables and is located on a network. Is there a way to only run code when a specifc [parameter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/parameter.htm) is altered? You'd think `parameter.altered == True` would do the trick but this seems no different than if `parameter.valueAsText` returns `True` in a logic test (has a value).

Making the feature class/tables parameter dependent of the workspace doesn't work because feature classes in datasets are ignored.

Code:

```
class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Copy Feature Classes And Relationship Classes"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        inGdb = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Input Geodatabase",
            name = "ingdb",
            datatype = "Workspace",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        outGdb = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Output Geodatabase",
            name = "outgdb",
            datatype = "Workspace",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        inFcs = arcpy.Parameter (
            displayName = "Feature Classes And Tables",
            name = "infcs",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)

        return [inGdb, outGdb, inFcs]

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        if not parameters [0].valueAsText:
            parameters [2].enabled = False
        ###below code runs whenever any new input is input!!!
        if parameters [0].valueAsText and parameters [0].altered: ##altered doesn't work! :(
            try: wst = arcpy.Describe (parameters [0].valueAsText).workspaceType
            except:
                parameters [2].filter.list = []
                parameters [2].value = None
                return
            if  wst == "LocalDatabase":
                parameters [2].enabled = True
                gdb = parameters [0].valueAsText
                arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
                fcs = []
                for typ in ["Point", "Polygon", "Polyline", "Multipoint"]:
                    fcs += ["{} (Feature Class)".format (fc) for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses (feature_type = typ)]
                fcs += ["{} (Table)".format (tab) for tab in arcpy.ListTables ()]
                datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets ()
                for dataset in datasets:
                    for typ in ["Point", "Polygon", "Polyline", "Multipoint"]:
                        dsFcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses (None, typ, dataset)
                        for dsFc in dsFcs:
                            fc = os.path.join (dataset, dsFc)
                            fcs += [fc]
                parameters [2].filter.list = fcs
            else:
                parameters [2].filter.list = []
                parameters [2].value = None
```

Comment: Can you introduce a global variable (currentValue) then in the sub if valueAsText != currentValue then return ?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for the response Michael. I tried globals but they didn't seem to work. I'll give it another go.

Comment: @MichaelStimson That did it! I just wasn't using globals correctly. Thanks. Please feel free to answer and I'll accept.

Comment: did you specify *global currentValue* in the def? Python is a bit finicky about that sort of thing, if you don't tell it you want to use the *existing global variable* it will assume that it's a new local variable (which has a value of None).

Comment: @MichaelStimson that’s exactly what I did wrong. I defined it as global at the start of the script but not in the def.

Comment: @user2856 This is a better answer. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @EmilBrundage done.  I couldn't answer before, too hard on a mobile device and couldn't test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "arcpy way ™" is to check `if parameters[0].altered and not parameters[0].hasBeenValidated:`

According to the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/customizing-tool-behavior-in-a-python-toolbox.htm):

> **altered**
>
> `altered` is true if the value of a parameter is changed... Once a
>   parameter has been altered, ***it remains altered*** until the user empties
>   (blanks out) the value, in which case it returns to being unaltered.
>
> **hasBeenValidated**
>
> `hasBeenValidated` is false if a parameter's value has
>   been modified by the user since the last time `updateParameters` and
>   internal validate were called. Once internal validate has been called,
>   geoprocessing automatically sets `hasBeenValidated` to true for every
>   parameter.
>
> `hasBeenValidated` ***is used to determine whether the user has changed a
>   value since the last call to*** `updateParameters`.

For example, a simplified version of your code (doesn't disable/enable, just empties/populates `parameters[2]`):

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]

class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = "A Tool"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        inGdb = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Input Geodatabase",
            name = "ingdb",
            datatype = "DEWorkspace",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")
        # Set the filter to accept only local geodatabases
        inGdb.filter.list = ["Local Database"]

        outGdb = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Output Geodatabase",
            name = "outgdb",
            datatype = "DEWorkspace",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")
        # Set the filter to accept only local geodatabases
        outGdb.filter.list = ["Local Database"]

        inFcs = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Feature Classes And Tables",
            name = "infcs",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)

        return [inGdb, outGdb, inFcs]

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):

        if not parameters[0].altered:

            parameters[2].filter.list = []
            parameters[2].value = None

        elif parameters[0].altered and not parameters[0].hasBeenValidated:

            gdb = parameters[0].valueAsText
            arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
            fcs = []
            for typ in ["Point", "Polygon", "Polyline", "Multipoint"]:
                fcs += ["{} (Feature Class)".format(fc) for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = typ)]
            fcs += ["{} (Table)".format(tab) for tab in arcpy.ListTables()]
            datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
            for dataset in datasets:
                for typ in ["Point", "Polygon", "Polyline", "Multipoint"]:
                    dsFcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(None, typ, dataset)
                    for dsFc in dsFcs:
                        fc = os.path.join(dataset, dsFc)
                        fcs += [fc]
            parameters[2].filter.list = fcs
```

Answer (score 2):

For this one a use of a global variable will help:

```
currentValue = '' # to avoid problems later give it an empty string

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
  global currentValue
  if parameters[0].valueAsText != currentValue:
    currentValue = parameters[0].valueAsText
    # the rest of your code
```

Python is a bit finicky about that sort of thing, if you don't tell it you want to use the existing global variable it will assume that it's a new local variable (which has a value of None).

Global variables are handy and have a purpose but I would warn future readers of this post to not over-use global variables.. I have read some articles that suggest that globals in python chew up memory needlessly.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a class instance variable (ie, a property) in the `__init__(self)` function as `self.currentValue`.  And check/update its value in `updateParameters()` as above.